# Convert str_to_date to YYYY-MM and keep 2 digit month format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want my date to show up with 2 digits in the month, but I can only seem to get 1. I've scoured the internet for a solution, and found some that seemed like they should have worked, but kept getting a 1064 Error Code. I just started learning SQL a couple days ago, so I may have come across the correct answer and just have no idea where in the query to put it.

This is how I connected to the db in mySQL workbench:

To connect to the MySQL Server, point your client program to:

host: applepie.cx67wtelpwox.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

username: public

port: 3306

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    concat(year, '-', month) AS theDate,
    dest,
    sum(1) AS numFlights,
    sum(cancelled) AS numCancelled,
    ((sum(Cancelled) / sum(1))) AS perCancelled
FROM flights WHERE year = 2013
    AND dest = 'SFO'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY perCancelled desc
```

This is what I get:

```
2013-7  SFO 15401   862 0.0560
2013-6  SFO 14768   503 0.0341
2013-8  SFO 15478   322 0.0208
```

This is what I want:

```
2013-07 SFO 15401   862 0.0560
2013-06 SFO 14768   503 0.0341
2013-08 SFO 15478   322 0.0208
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: Sorry! Is my edit what you need?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is the client program. The RDBMS you're using is simply MySQL. I'll re-tag your question appropriately. Also, if that's actually your password, I wouldn't necessarily post it on the web if I were you.

Comment: Seriously did you just post your login credentials, you need to change those asap! (i checked)

Comment: I appreciate it so much, thank you.

Comment: @CRossi don't just remove the password, also delete the other info and change it on the server asap!

Comment: @CRossi - Unfortunately everyone can still see the edits in stack overflow. You better change the password asap.

Comment: @Ramesh It was actually just the public password every person in my class gets, not a personal one of any kind, but I do appreciate your advice.

Comment: Not to mention, the port is just used to get publicly accessible historical flight information. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lpad for build a 2 char length string for month

```
SELECT 
    concat(year, '-', lpad(month,  2,'0')) AS theDate,
    dest,
    sum(1) AS numFlights,
    sum(cancelled) AS numCancelled,
    ((sum(Cancelled) / sum(1))) AS perCancelled
FROM flights WHERE year = 2013
    AND dest = 'SFO'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY perCancelled desc
```

Comment: Is that query really valid?!?

Comment: @scaisEdge I've clicked your the checkmark for your answer. Thank you for the link on how to "accept" an answer, and thank you again for your help. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: The GROUP BY. According to ANSI SQL it's invalid, but I know MySQL does things in different ways, so I don't know here.

Comment: It's a good observation...   the query is valid for mysql  .. but also for SQL standard  .. because dest and year (the others column not in group by) are limited  to a single value by the where condition  ..